# Can't get WiFi to work on Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377

Tags: networking, drivers, acer, connection, atheros

I had my Acer Aspire E5-574g Laptop for some weeks now and use it in dualboot with Ubuntu and Windows 10. On Windows 10 WiFi is working perfectly fine, no problems at all. But it isn't working on Ubuntu or other Linuxes at all. I actually want to switch to Linux completely but of course I can't without working WiFi. I really tried everything I could. I googled for days on how to fix the problem. I didn't really find that much except for this: [Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless not working on lenovo with 14.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3)
Which didn't help at all for me. Sometimes WiFi is working but extreeemely slow and just for some seconds. It's connecting (or showing that it's connected) but doesn't load anything. It's actually working with a WiFi dongle but that's really only a temporary solution for me.

I already tried it with Ubuntu and Kali Linux but it never worked, so it seems to be a problem with Linux. I'm about to give up on Linux.

Comment: I am using wired network because of this problem. Backed to 1990.

Comment: Removing (or renaming) `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing exactly the same issues as you are mentioning, after weeks of useless trouble shooting I spend 40 € getting a Netgear A6100 WIFI USB adapter, now wifi is working stable & fast, 434 Mb/s.

After each kernel update I retry with the Atheros but till now no luck. 
I agree not the most elegant solution, but a working one

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while I was on Router Wifi channel 13 here in Argentina on a Acer Aspire 3. Changed Router Wifi channel to 11 and it appeared and worked with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Kali Linux with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wlan the issue in my case was a conflicting firmware.

1 sudo airmon-ng check kill
2 sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
3 sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
4 sudo NetworkManager Start

Line 1 in order to simply kill the processes that may or may not be utilizing the wlan0 card. (your card may be in a different position than mine i.e wlan1, wlan2 etc)

Line 2 is the ultimate fix in my situation as firmware-5.bin is what actually works for QCA9377 You may want to make a back up copy of the firmware-6.bin before you remove it, but I did not care enough to keep the file.

line 3 & 4 simply because I am too lazy to restart the OS and wanted to be online instantly.

Once in the past I had to run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` along with lines 3 & 4 again to get internet access.

I hope this points anyone else in the correct direction as I spent hours searching before finally finding this answer.