# My wifi keeps on disconnecting

Tags: wireless, atheros

I am new to Linux and recently dual booted the LTS Ubuntu and until now it has worked fine. Now it randomly disconnects from WiFi and I can't even use the WiFi settings to connect back on. I have to restart it every time.
Please suggest a fix. I am not confident in Linux command, therefore I have tried to do much.

I have wireless card - Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377

Comment: You need to check for certain logs. One is systemctl. Then you need to find out if there is any driver issue there.

Comment: Please define what you mean by the "*LTS Ubuntu*".  Ubuntu releases LTS products every second year, each having kernel stack choice with the default set by installation media; we currently don't know what release you're using. Is this Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? and what release of that product?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 disconnects periodically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140508/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-disconnects-periodically)