# Unable to connect to Wi-Fi, Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, lubuntu, atheros

I am using Lubuntu 18.04. I am unable to connect to my Wi-Fi network. I just happened since an hour ago.

In my edit connections options it is showing my Wi-Fi name:

**VodafoneMobileWifi-51BB**

which was last active 1 hour ago.

My **Enable Networking** and **Enable Wi-Fi** options are checked.

But my laptop is suddenly unable to connect to the network.

My Wi-Fi adapter is **Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377**

I followed the instructions given in the first answer of this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3)

```
sudo make defconfig-ath10k
```

gives me the prompt:

```
Generating local configuration database from kernel ... done.
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o zconf.tab.o zconf.tab.c
cc   conf.o zconf.tab.o   -o conf
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
```

and

```
sudo make
```

gives me the prompt:

```
make[5]: 'conf' is up to date.
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
  CC [M]  /home/saptak/backports-20151120/compat/main.o
  LD [M]  /home/saptak/backports-20151120/compat/compat.o
  CC [M]  /home/saptak/backports- 
  20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/main.o
  CC [M]  /home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.o
/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c: In function ‘dynamic_country_user_possible’:
/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c:119:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘config_enabled’; did you mean ‘x2apic_enabled’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (config_enabled(CPTCFG_ATH_REG_DYNAMIC_USER_CERT_TESTING))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      x2apic_enabled
/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c:119:21: error: ‘CPTCFG_ATH_REG_DYNAMIC_USER_CERT_TESTING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (config_enabled(CPTCFG_ATH_REG_DYNAMIC_USER_CERT_TESTING))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c:119:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c: In function ‘ath_reg_dyn_country_user_allow’:
/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c:191:22: error: ‘CPTCFG_ATH_REG_DYNAMIC_USER_REG_HINTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (!config_enabled(CPTCFG_ATH_REG_DYNAMIC_USER_REG_HINTS))
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.o' failed
make[7]: *** [/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:606: recipe for target '/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath' failed
make[6]: *** [/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/ath] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:606: recipe for target '/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless' failed
make[5]: *** [/home/saptak/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/saptak/backports-20151120' failed
make[4]: *** [_module_/home/saptak/backports-20151120] Error 2
Makefile.build:6: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile.real:88: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: Try restarting network-manager. You can do this by opening the terminal and typing "sudo service network-manager restart"

Comment: network-manager restart done, still no wi-fi connection. I am formatting my laptop now to install ubuntu. It has much less problems.