# QCA9377 USB wireless recurrent problem

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, usb, atheros

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I tried the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3), however my attempts to reproduce the results are unsuccessful. Repeated trips to the well to get newer versions of the software won't compile correctly with repeated implicit declarations of functions like setup_timer() and config_enable().  Is there some switch (or option) that needs to be set for a successful compile?

`uname -a` returns:

```
4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov15 . . .
```

Located `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0` on the machine (suggested by Jan2016 post--wireless not working on Acer Aspire E 15).

After I get that behind me, I want to use the Linksys USB wireless adapter, WUSB6100M with Qualcomm QCA9377 chipset, to provide internet access to my second computer (Dell OptiPlex-755, 32-bit machine). The drivers provided by Linksys only support recent Windows operating systems.

The results of `lsusb`

```
$ lsusb  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13b1:0042 Linksys 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The plugin USB adapter is at ID 13b1:0042.

```
$ dmesg |grep ath  
[  176.424811] usb 1-4: WARNING: ath10k USB support is incomplete, don't expect anything to work!
[  176.424852] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath10k_usb
[  176.565542] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2
[  176.565572] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2
[  176.587778] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-6.bin failed with error -2
[  176.587808] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-5.bin failed with error -2
[  176.587830] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-4.bin failed with error -2
[  176.587852] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-3.bin failed with error -2
[  176.587874] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-2.bin failed with error -2
[  176.587879] usb 1-4: Failed to find firmware-N.bin (N between 2 and 6) from ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0: -2
```

I did suggested firmware update. `dmesg |grep ath` returned:

```
[  139.925263] usb 1-4: WARNING: ath10k USB support is incomplete, don't expect anything to work!
[  139.925310] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath10k_usb
[  140.073492] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2
[  140.073521] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2
[  140.095716] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-6.bin failed with error -2
[  140.155758] usb 1-4: failed to fetch board data for bus=usb,vendor=13b1,device=0042,subsystem-vendor=0000,subsystem-device=0000 from ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
```

I added additional file (board-2.bin), rebooted and executed commands `ls` and `dmesg |grep ath` Files `pre-cal-usb-1-4.bin`, `cal-usb-1-4.bin`, and `firmware-usb-6.bin` never unpacked (i.e. not found) in extract directory.

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0$ `ls`

```
board-2.bin  firmware-5.bin      notice_ath10k_firmware-5.txt
board.bin    firmware-usb-5.bin
```

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0$ `dmesg |grep ath`

```
[  186.698686] usb 1-4: WARNING: ath10k USB support is incomplete, don't expect anything to work!
[  186.698739] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath10k_usb
[  186.711510] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2
[  186.711551] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2`[  186.733726] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-6.bin failed with error -2
[  186.793152] usb 1-4: failed to fetch board data for bus=usb,vendor=13b1,device=0042,subsystem-vendor=0000,subsystem-device=0000 from ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
```

__------------------------------------------------------------------------

After file move and adding link, `dmesg |grep ath` returns:

`[   27.018040] usb 1-4: WARNING: ath10k USB support is incomplete, don't expect anything to work!`

`[   27.018087] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath10k_usb`

`[   27.066345] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2`

`[   27.066375] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-usb-1-4.bin failed with error -2`

`[   27.088567] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-6.bin failed with error -2`

`[   27.164838] usb 1-4: failed to fetch board data for bus=usb,vendor=13b1,device=0042,subsystem-vendor=0000,subsystem-device=0000 from ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin`

__--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: First of all, the accepted answer is old old old. Second, it is the driver for the PCI version of the device; yours is the USB version and it uses a different driver. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It's my first post. I'm aware of the age, but needed to start somewhere. To your request see below.

Comment: however, cut/paste is too long for comment box. Editing original post.

Comment: May we also see: `dmesg | grep ath` We suspect that you may need firmware.

Comment: adding dmesg to post

Answer (score 1):

Your dmesg indicates that you are missing firmware. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install git
git clone -b usb https://github.com/erstrom/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0
cp firmware-usb-5-wusb6100m.bin firmware-usb-5.bin
sudo cp firmware-usb-5.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
```

**Edit**: Also do:

```
sudo cp board-2.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

**EDIT 2**: Move the eeprom file to /lib/firmware:

```
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp eeprom_qca9377_7_1p1_Robin_clpc_fcc.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
ln -s eeprom_qca9377_7_1p1_Robin_clpc_fcc.bin board-usb.bin
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Resource: https://marc.info/?l=linux-wireless&m=148434332728333&w=2

Comment: still seeing errors after update and reboot, see original thread with dmesg output

Comment: There is also a board-2.bin in the files you cloned. I will edit the answer to transfer it, too. Afterwards, reboot and again show: `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: moved additional file--still no joy. See thread above.

Comment: See my edit #2 above.

Comment: Moved fcc file to /lib/ and added link. Joy continues to elude us. See above.

Comment: I regret that I have no other suggestions. We have done all that I can find to suggest. Please consider a different supported out of the box device.

Comment: chili,thanks for taking a swing at this. Do you know the purpose of the three files that generated the failed with error -2 messages? I'm annoyed with Linksys for not providing Linux drivers for there hardware and will return the adapter. DE

Comment: It looks for and fails to find various firmware files. It *does* find firmware-usb-5.bin, however.  You might email Linksys and ask for help. Feel free to refer them to this question; perhaps they will have corrections or other suggestions.

Comment: Yesterday, I included the URL at the top of this page in a post to the Linksys support page. Haven't heard back.

Comment: I called Linksys and directed their attention to this thread, but was told (again), after an escalation and callback, that they only support the MS Windows operating system. I will returned the WUSB6100M adapter.