# Ubuntu 22.10 wifi driver not found in lenovo E41-25 wifi chip QCA9377 802.11cc wifi adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros, 22.10, ubuntu-drivers

This is my first question asking in this forum.

Please help me out.

1.I have dual operating system in my laptop. one is linux ubuntu 22.10 distro another one windows 10.

2.in widows 10 WIFI working normally.but in ubuntu it's not found

3.last entire week searched lot in google i tried varies drivers like RLTx and so.

4.then i got to know for my wifi QCA9377 802.11cc wifi adapter driver have firmware in auth10k

5.i downloaded from github and copy firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 into firmware-5.bin

> sudo rm -r ath10k

i'm try to install into kernal module it's using

> sudo rmmod ath10k_pci

even though its not working..

5.please recommend easy way to install wifi driver

Comment: Thanks so much. i'll try this one. i spent week  for this thanks  a lot

Comment: Welcome to this Ubuntu Q&A site (*this is a question & answer site; https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums*).  Mostly FYI, but your command `rmmod` is *remove module* which is used to remove unwanted modules; you use `insmod` to insert/install modules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless not working on lenovo with 14.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3)

Comment: @24601 Nothing above suggests that her/his wireless device is Broadcom.