# I am not able to connect wifi through wifi adapter while my laptop's inbuilt wifi is doing so

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager

I am using Dell laptop and it has old wifi driver. So I am using **Tp-link AC1300 T3U** for my wifi connection. When I connect to wifi, it shows connected in settings but actually there is **no internet** access and a **Question mark is showing on wifi mark**.

I have changed DNS and the problem remain same. If I connect the same wifi with my laptop's wifi then it got connected and also have internet access.

Please help me to solve this problem, else I have to shift to windows which I don't want.
I provide all detail which you want. for now I am at Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Result of following command is:
`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`
for above command

```
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

and for  `rfkill list all`
the result is:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: phy4: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

for `ifconfig`

```
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c0:3e:ba:3b:85:5c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 22569  bytes 2304229 (2.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22569  bytes 2304229 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 5c:ba:ef:08:fd:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 369  bytes 111581 (111.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 626  bytes 134395 (134.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx788cb51b5acb: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.28  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::6c8f:c934:8ddc:6093  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2409:4056:209d:aafd:529f:4ea5:b291:dab1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2409:4056:209d:aafd:43b4:de51:b8b:b7b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 78:8c:b5:1b:5a:cb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2019  bytes 815724 (815.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2080  bytes 404593 (404.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I provide more detail if anyone wants...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless not working on lenovo with 14.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3)