# Wifi is not working in my lenovo ideapad

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo, atheros

Ever since i installed linux my wifi is not working. I  am using lenovo ideapad E41-25. I have tried many things but didnot work. Wifi works in windows but on ubuntu.Any amount of help will be apreciated as i am a newbie on linux.
The brand is qualcomm realtek atheros QCA9377

```
ustan@mustan-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0              unblocked unblocked
mustan@mustan-Lenovo-E41-25:~$
```

Comment: We can't really help, we don't know what OS/release you're asking about (*and if a Ubuntu LTS release, which kernel stack you've opted to use given there is choice; kernel stack choice impacting kernel modules which are commonly called drivers*).  Did you try and follow any documentation, eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  where step 3.1 is most useful (*Device Recognition and Operation*) being a very useful starting point for Linux *driver* issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless not working on lenovo with 14.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3)